# create a relationship with existing object - core data in swift

Tags: core-data

I have two entities Events and Partecipant. I already have events in event table. I want to create a relationship between participant with existing event passed as variable during the insertion of new participant in event table. (i.e. insert event -> go tot page "add participant to event" insert participant. My code is:

```
  event.name! (passed with"segue") 
  func addPartecipantInEvent() {
    let newPartecipant = Partecipants(entity:          CoreDataController.sharedIstance.entityPartecipants!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:  CoreDataController.sharedIstance.context)



         let partecipantName = partecipantTxt.text!

            let eventName = event.name!




    newPartecipant.setValue(partecipantName, forKey: "name")

    eventName.addPartecipant(newPartecipant)
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way?

Comment: error at the last line: "value of type String has no member of 'addPartecipant'

Comment: What is the type of `event` and of `eventName`?

Comment: The type of event is string as the same of eventName

Answer (score 0):

If `eventName` is a string, then the error is expected. Strings don't have a method called `addPartecipant`. If your entity is `Event`, that method probably exists on `event` but not on `event.name`.

Comment: Yes but if I put event.addPartcipant(newPartecipant) it seems that nothing happens... How can I check if the relationship has been done?

Comment: You could check the value of the relationship by looking it up on either the participant or the event.

Comment: I've tried to print result: event.addPartecipant(newPartecipant)
        print("Partecipant \(newPartecipant.pName) added to event \(newPartecipant.events?.name)") and the console grab the result ( i.e Participant X added to event Y). Can we assume that the relationship is created?

Comment: Sounds like it. Why do you think that "nothing happens"? What do you expect to happen that is not happening?

Comment: Because when I try to grab value (I.e. valueLbl.text = participants.events?.name) I got error "unexpected found nil while unwrapping optional value".